# Proxy Server on Kubuntu 15.04 not working

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu, internet, proxy

I recently installed Kubuntu 15.04. I can connect normally through LAN and wifi that requires no proxy.

The problem is that the wifi in our college requires proxy with authentication. I have already done setting-up the settings (http proxy and port) in the Proxy - System Settings but it seems that it wont work.

But the weird thing is that the Internet works when I apply the settings on Firefox's own connection settings menu. I have also tried surfing the internet for some help (I managed to make it work on the terminal (by making the apt.conf file) whenever doing an update or install,etc) but still, I wasn't able to solve this problem since I still can't connect to the internet using the system settings. I use Google Chrome as a test if I can connect through the proxy or not since Google Chrome uses the system proxy settings.

Here is the image of my settings:

[image]