# How to change network proxy settings in Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, kubuntu, proxy

I am new to linux and I have kubuntu 15.10. I connect to a internet network at my university which has proxy settings. So wanted to know how to make changes at the Kubuntu system level for this proxy.

I went to System Settings > Network > Proxy and in the available options, I chose the manual options (Use Manually Specified Proxy Configuration) and entered the appropriate values. [At the firefox side, I have set "Use System Proxy".] But this setting is not working. 
If I enter the appropriate values in the firefox network settings, I am able to connect to the internet.

Can someone please tell how to make system level proxy changes? And also, why the configuration I set at Network>Proxy>Manual Proxy does not work?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: A similar question has been asked before. But sadly, it does not have an answer :(     http://askubuntu.com/questions/644749/proxy-server-on-kubuntu-15-04-not-working-need-help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure proxy authentication to work with Ubuntu Software Center?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/77449/how-to-configure-proxy-authentication-to-work-with-ubuntu-software-center)

Comment: @muru - Thanks for the suggestion. But my question is for Kubuntu; and the answer you suggested is for Ubuntu. I had ubuntu 3 days back and I knew where to set the system level network proxy. But in Kubuntu, even if I change at the system settings>network>proxy, its not reflecting for firefox. So, I think my problem might be different.

Comment: It's a command line method. Works the same on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks! I will see how to do that. Excuse for troubling you again - so the method of providing proxies in the system settings UI does not work?

Answer (score 0):

for the proxy settings you can see in
 https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Proxyserver
in my environment that worked fine

Comment: Thanks! But the site is in german, which I cant understand. And moreover, going by the screenshots given there, I think I have done something similar. But surprised that my settings are not working.